# Error importing tensorflow

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, deep-learning

I installed tensorflow and CUDA using the .deb file. I also installed CUDNN. However, when I try to import the library in python, it is giving me this error.

```
 >>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python
pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've added the following lines to my .bashrc file

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64"
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda/bin
```

Comment: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64`

Answer (score 1):

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64`

and make sure that you have `libcudart.so.7.5.lib` inside that path.

Answer (score 1):

Like fabrizioM mentioned, you must have the `libcudart.so.7.5.lib` inside `/usr/local/cuda/lib64`. To do that, follow the [instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html#optional-linux-enable-gpu-support) given by TensorFlow:

```
tar xvzf cudnn-7.5-linux-x64-v5.1-ga.tgz
sudo cp cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include
sudo cp cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64
sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*
```